# Is taking Tea with using Tea-cup from left hand is haram?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, food

Eating with Left hand is Haram, in that concern I want to know that:

Is taking Tea with using Tea-cup from left hand is haram?

Comment: It's a cultural norm to show courtesy; not Haram as such.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to elaborate under what perspective you're asking from? Most interpretations of Islam don't outright *forbid* eating with the left-hand, so as phrased you're likely just going to attract a lot of people telling you why they don't think its *haram* at all rather than answering the *actual* question.

Answer (score 2):

Salamu Alaikum

There is no Haram in drinking what is Halal. But it is Sunnah to Eat and Drink with your right hand and do other things such as cleaning with your left hand.

> Narrated Az-Zuhri:
>
> From Salim, from his father, that the Messenger of
>   Allah (ﷺ) said: "When one of you eats, then let him eat with his right
>   hand, and let him drink with his right hand, for indeed Ash-Shaitan
>   eats with his left hand, and he drinks with his left hand."
>
> Grade : Sahih (Darussalam)

We must thrive to not follow the way (Sunnah) of the devil. Hense taking the advise of Rasoul'Allah (saws) is a good practice since it makes us better believers and closer to him.

> Ye have indeed in the Messenger of Allah a beautiful pattern (of conduct) for any one whose hope is in Allah and the Final Day, and who engages much in the Praise of Allah.
>
> Quran 33:21

Answer (score 1):

```
            In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful
```

> Is taking Tea with using Tea-cup from left hand is haram?

According to Shia Islam (and likewise I think Sunni Islam) it is not considered as a haram act as @goldPseudo mentioned in his comment as he said “Most interpretations of Islam don't outright forbid eating with the left-hand,…” of course perhaps it can be counted as makruh act, but it would be permissible at least according to often sects as much as it is inferred from different Muslims.

On the other hand, on the whole, Islam suggests the Moslems to use right hand as much as possible, a reason can be related to “Ashab-al-Yamin” as the right path. Since apparently the righteous was is considered as the right side, not left. Moreover, I have heard that the Prophet (s) and Shia’s Imam always used to eat by their right hand (unless in some specific situation which had to …)